# Correct use-case for Concurrency::task_group

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, concurrency, task

The documentation says: "`task_group` class represents a collection of **parallel work** which can be waited on or canceled."

1). Do I take it to mean that tasks need to be logically related (but broken down) and that you will ideally need to wait on them elsewhere to collate the results?

1. IOW, is it possible to use task_group to just schedule asynchronous tasks that basically have no relation to each other (as an analogy: sort of like dumping each iteration of some processing activity in a queue and picking it up for execution by another thread)? Each of them just execute and die away and as a result I wouldn't even have to wait or cancel them.

(I do understand that the task_group dtor will throw an exception if I don't cancel or wait on incomplete tasks. Lets forget that for the moment and only focus on whether I am using it for the right purpose).

Answer (score -1):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx) has an explanation on task groups - not bad.

In a nutshell,
use task groups (the `concurrency::task_group` class or the `concurrency::parallel_invoke` algorithm) when you want to decompose parallel work into smaller pieces and then wait for those smaller pieces to complete.